# The details of proving that suspension of a space is an example of a Co - H - group.

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory

Here is the proposition I want to prove:

> [image]

And here is the definition of the suspension:

> [image]

And here is the first part of what I want to prove:

[image]

Where $q_{1}$ is the restrictions of the projection map $p_{1}$ to $X \vee X .$

And here is the proof of the first condition but for loop spaces being grouplike:

[image]

**My question is:**

How will the proof of the first requirement for suspensions being co-group differ from the corresponding one for loops being grouplike? could anyone explain that for me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $q_1c : SA \to SA$ is explicitly given by
$$(q_1c)(\langle a, t \rangle) = \begin{cases} \langle a, 2t \rangle & 0 \le t \le 1/2 \\  * & 1/2 \le t \le 1 \end{cases}$$
A homotopy $q_1c \simeq id$ is given by
$$H : SA \times I \to SA, H(\langle a, t \rangle, s) = \begin{cases} \langle a, (2-s)t \rangle & 0 \le t \le 1/(2-s) \\  * & 1/(2-s) \le t \le 1 \end{cases}$$
The case $q_2c \simeq id$ is similar.

Comment: Can you show me the drawing for it, please?

Comment: Sorry, I never post drawings.

Comment: I do not understand how you thought about your homotopy ..... specifically why your line is described as $1/(2-s)$ ..... could you explain this please?

Comment: $SA$ is a quotient of $A \times I$. The homotopy $H$ is obtained by a homotopy $H'$ on $A \times I$ which is compatible with the quotient map $\pi$. In fact, $H'(a,t,s) =  (a, (2-s)t)$ for $0 \le t \le t \le 1/(2-s)$ and $H'(a,t,s) =  (a, 1)$ for $1/(2-s) \le t \le 1$. At time $s$ it stretches $A \times [0,1/(2-s)]$ linearly to $A \times I$ (for $t=0$ we get $(a,0) $, fot $t= 1/(2-s)$ we get $(a,1)$) and compresses $A \times [1/(2-s),1]$ to $A \times \{1\}$. Note that for $s=0$ we have $1/(2-s) = 1/2$ and for $s=1$ we have $1/(2-s) = 1$.

Comment: Note that this works "fiberwise", i.e. $ H'$ has the form $H' =id_A \times H''$, where $H''$ is a homotopy between maps $I \to X =  I$. The homotopy $H''$ is a standard construct showing that for any path $u$ in (an arbitrary space)  $X$ we have a path homotopy $u * c_{u(1)} \simeq u$, where $c_{u(1)}$ is the constant path at $u(1)$. This result says that the equivalence classes of constant paths are "right identities" in  the fundamental grupoid of $X$.